# Are there any better ways to check this condition in Java 8?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I need to simplify following code in java.  Are there any way to using set and do this ?

```
      if (!(((AdministrativeState.PLANNED == dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState()) ||
             (AdministrativeState.MISSED == dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState()) ||
             (AdministrativeState.SKIPPED == dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState()) ||
             (AdministrativeState.SELF_ADMINISTERED == dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState()) ||
(AdministrativeState.SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE == dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState())) &&
        isSpecialDoseType(doseDetail))
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(AdministrativeState.PLANNED, AdministrativeState.MISSED, AdministrativeState.SKIPPED, AdministrativeState.SELF_ADMINISTERED, AdministrativeState.SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE).contains(dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState())`

Comment: Static imports?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Set`, you can initialize the valid enum types and perform a contains as @shmosel also pointed out in the comments :

```
Set<AdministrativeState> administrativeStates = Set.of(PLANNED, MISSED, SKIPPED, SELF_ADMINISTERED, SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE)
if (!administrativeStates.contains(dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState())
        || !isSpecialDoseType(doseDetail))
```

Comment: In case of `enum` values, you might prefer `EnumSet.of(…)`. Or just test for the opposite of all these named values, if the remaining cases have less values.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what data types are we dealing with here so I can't give you a better answer until you can shed more light on this. But assuming `AdministrativeState` is an enumerator you can do something like this:

```
public enum AdministrativeState {

    NONE, PLANNED, MISSED, SKIPPED, SELF_ADMINISTERED,
    SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE;
}

public static class OccasionModel {

    AdministrativeState state;

    OccasionModel() {
        this.state = AdministrativeState.NONE;
    }

    OccasionModel setState(AdministrativeState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

public static void checkAdminState(OccasionModel model) {

    OccasionModel dispensingOccasionModel = model;

    if (dispensingOccasionModel.state != AdministrativeState.NONE) {
        // Do something here...
    }
    else System.out.println("Administrative state is not set yet");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    checkAdminState(new OccasionModel());
    checkAdminState(new OccasionModel().setState(AdministrativeState.PLANNED));
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you're looking for but this doesn't have anything to do with Java 8 in particular. If you can provide more information about what's what I can help you out further.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the get methods have no side effects and return always the same value (within the scope of your sample), 
you can use refactoring
**Extract variable**

s =dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState());

Also, you can statically import AdministrativeState.*.

You then get:

```
 AdministrativeState s =dispensingOccasionModel.getOccasionDTO().getAdminState();

 if (!(((PLANNED == s) || (MISSED == s ) || (SKIPPED == s) || 
(SELF_ADMINISTERED == s) || 
(SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE == s))
 && isSpecialDoseType(doseDetail))
```

Then taking into account that the double pipe (Boolean OR) operator has quite a lot priority you can remove the parentheses around single comparisons:

```
 (a==b)||(c==d) ===> a==b||c==d.
```

You get:

```
if (!((PLANNED == s ||
MISSED == s  || 
SKIPPED == s || 
SELF_ADMINISTERED == s || 
SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE == s)) 
&& isSpecialDoseType(doseDetail))
```

There are double parentheses after ! And before &&. They can be reduced to a single one.

```
  if (!(PLANNED == s ||
 MISSED == s 
 || SKIPPED == s || 
 SELF_ADMINISTERED == s || 
 SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE == s)
  && isSpecialDoseType(doseDetail))
```

Now you can use the rule of inverting logical expressions:

```
  !(a==b|| c==d) ===> a!=b&&c!=d,
```

Which basically inverts all the operations due to the NOT (!) Operator. Since you will have only && operators left to combine Boolean sub expressions, then you can drop the parentheses.

```
if (PLANNED != s 
&& MISSED != s
&& SKIPPED != s
&& SELF_ADMINISTERED != s
&& SELF_ADMINISTERED_BY_RANGE != s
&& isSpecialDoseType(doseDetail)
)
```

Now if you have good domain knowledge you could know if you can combine self
Administered into one variable and shipped/missed into another to have something like: neither ( planned nor stoppedOrMissed nor selfAdministered)&& isSpecial. But without such knowledge I would live the expression at this level.